# How can I GIT REWORD from the command line?

Tags: git, git-amend

Is there a way to reword a git commit message from command line? Something like

`git commit --amend --message="New message"`

Similar as we can change author name via `git commit --amend --author="New Author Name <email@address.com>"`

Comment: Have you tried your own advice? `git commit --amend --message="New message"` works for me.

Comment: @phd How did you make it work? It does not work in my case.

Comment: I just ran `git commit --amend -m xxx` and verified the change with `git show`. No magic.

Comment: `-m` did the trick, as `--message` does not exist.

Comment: It exists in the [latest docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit--mltmsggt) and in my man page; `--message=xxx` works for me. I have git version 2.11. Is your git older?

Comment: `git --version 
git version 2.17.1
`

Comment: it's probably the syntax. thanks